# Site with collection of exercises in TCS?

Tags: soft-question, big-list

Is there a website with a large collection of exercises for theoretical computer science, sorted by topics? I know that many exercises can be found in different textbooks, I'm looking for an online database, preferably with hints/solutions included.

Answer (score 3):

[100 exercises in the theory of automata and formal languages](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/60795/)

https://algomuse.net/
It's a kind of competition but problems are from research papers.

Here http://www.openproblemgarden.org/
Some problems have hints.

https://a3nm.net/work/research/questions/#other-lists-of-open-problems

In this book, each chapter have some exercise: 
https://files.boazbarak.org/introtcs/lnotes_book.pdf

Comment: I don't see any collection of exercises on any of these sites.

Comment: @domotorp Prof. I updated the answer!

Comment: I said no textbooks.